# Empty the contents of a textarea after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a comment box (textarea) inside a dialog. If the comment is successfully saved I want to clear the contents of the textarea and close the dialog box. ATM the dialog box will close but I need to wipe its contents.

```
<textarea id="CommentBox" type="text" runat="server" rows="7" 
maxlength="2000" /> 

if (CommentSuccessfullyUpdated == "TRUE") 
{
//empty the comment box??
//something like
$("#CommentBox").empty();

//closes the dialog box
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

Thanks for any replies

---

Edit:
Thanks for the help guys. It is running through the code but its not working. I think it has to do with in order to pick up the correct vales and resolve a biding issue I had to use:

```
 function SubmitButton() {
            var commentBoxData = $('#<%=CommentBox.ClientID%>').val();
           }
```

When run through with a breakpoint returns:

```
function SubmitButton() {
            var commentBoxData = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CommentBox').val();
}
```

AND:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CommentBox" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CommentBox" type="text" rows="7" maxlength="2000"> </textarea>
```

So Im guessing im not referencing the same textarea when I try to empty it.
Also tried

```
$("#CommentBox.ClientID").val('');
```

but no joy....ay ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#CommentBox').val('');
```

Use the `val()` method, passing in an empty string.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val

Also, your mark up is wrong. `textarea` isn't a self-closing element. You need a `</textarea>` tag. And the `type="text"` isn't necessary (probably not actually valid either)

As per your edit, you can either set the IDs to be static at the top of your .aspx file (I think it's `ClientID="static"`)

Or you can use a different selector:

```
$('textarea').filter('[id*=CommentBox]').val('');
```

Comment: @Mick - Updated my answer based on your edit.

Comment: Good job the different select worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

You can use `val`:

```
$("#CommentBox").val('');
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/KhPM6/1/

**Edit**:

You are not referencing the `ASP.NET` generated text area correctly.  As you have shown in your question, you need to reference it like:

```
$('#<%=CommentBox.ClientID%>').val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   $('textarea#CommentBox').val('');
```